# tideSDK, jquery, XMLHttpRequest, and absolute URL's

Tags: javascript, jquery, titanium, appcelerator, tidesdk

I'm using TideSDK to get content from a website.  I will need to pre fill in form data from the database on this website eventually.

I'm able to get the page and store it to a variable.
I'm able to parse our the relative URL's with alert()'s.
But I'm not able to replace the body with the corrected body
  `$('html').replaceWith(html);`  Jquery should be in memory so I don't have to worry about replacing html right?

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.  If an image or URL is absolute it works fine, but if it's relative it doesn't work.  I don't have access to fix the website with absolute url's.

My demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/Cs5MC/13/  Changed from html to body in demo

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, if this is an implementation of Titanium, you will need to use the Ti Network api discussed at [the this doc.](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Network.HTTPClient)

Pulling JSON data and using it is much the same, with a callback, as it would be with jQuery or any regular xhr request.

I hope that it helps.

By the way, using jQuery - which is heavily dependent upon the dom to do it's work - you will always have to be careful whether an expected dom structure is actually present - which it may not be with the titanium platform without a web view, although I am not familiar with the TideSDK and may stand corrected on that side.

Comment: Ti Network API is buggy doesn't work well.  https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/103
I've tried it both ways.  But thanks for the input